# MySQL Error with code

Tags: mysql

I keep getting an error with this code.

Error 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ‘default  ' ', originalcost decimal(10,2) not null default 0, current at line 3

```
Create table computer_inventory ( 
     assetnumber int(10) not null default 0,
     manufacturer ENUM('Dell', 'IBM', ' ') NOT NULL, default ' ', 
     originalcost decimal(10,2) not null default 0, 
     currentvalue decimal(10,2) not null default 0, 
     boughtfrom varchar(20) not null default ' ', 
     instock tinyint(1) not null default 0, 
     currentuser varchar(20) not null default ' ',
     userphonenum varchar(13) not null default ' ',
     boughtdate datetime not null default '0000-00-00'
 );
```

Any suggestions?

**EDIT** I found the comma in the wrong place. I must make an error saying "You must enter in "Dell" or "IBM" ". Does anyone know how to send that error??

Comment: are you sure about `manufacturer ENUM('Dell', 'IBM', ' ') NOT NULL**,** default ' ', `: semicolon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have used a comma after `NOT NULL` remove this comma

```
CREATE TABLE computer_inventory ( 
     assetnumber INT(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
     manufacturer ENUM('Dell', 'IBM', ' ') NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ', 
     originalcost DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
     currentvalue DECIMAL(10,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
     boughtfrom VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ', 
     instock TINYINT(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0, 
     currentuser VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
     userphonenum VARCHAR(13) NOT NULL DEFAULT ' ',
     boughtdate DATETIME NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
 );
```

[**Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/85edff)

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thank you. Another quick question.. If I wanted to send an error message saying "You must enter Dell or IBM".. How would I do that?